# How to pass object through pages that swtich via Tabs?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm programming an app with MAUI where I have an object called `Company` that is initialized in the `MainPage`

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    Company company { get; set; } = new Company();
```

and I want that object to be shared across two pages that switch between one another through  a tabs system run on the `AppShell`.

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<Shell
x:Class="Work_Tasks.AppShell"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Work_Tasks"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Work_Tasks.Pages">

<TabBar>
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage"
        Icon="home.png"/>
    <ShellContent
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AddPersonel}"
        Route="AddPersonel"
        Icon="add_contact.png"/>
</TabBar>
```

I want to avoid making the object `static`. Is there any way of passing the object through both or more pages? How should I go about it?

Comment: instead of passing it back and forth, make it a property of your App class so all pages can access it

Comment: Wait. How do I call it in the .cs for the pages?

Comment: use `Application.Current` to get a reference to the `App` object (this works in Xamarin Forms, I believe it should also work in MAUI)

Comment: @Jason Im having trouble doing it tbh. Is App a property of Application.Current?

Comment: No, it is the App object.  You may need to cast it first.  I can give you a fuller example later

Comment: Cast Application.Current as App?

Comment: Yes, try that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had this problem, I would probably go for something like this. Create class:

```
public class CompanyContainer
{
    public Company Company { get; set; } = new Company();
}
```

Now register it in MauiProgramm.cs as a singleton

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CompanyContainer>();
```

Now you can inject this instance through constructor to your page:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly CompanyContainer _companyContainer;
    
    public MainPage(CompanyContainer container)
    {
        _companyContainer = container;
    }
}
```

This should solve your issue. You can also make it as a property with public getter in MainPage if you need. And one more thing. In c# by convention we usually write property names with capital letter.